# App Search doesn't open in Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, android-12, search

I recently got an update on my phone to Android Version 12. Before this update, when I would scroll through my Apps I had a search bar on top where I could text-search through my installed Apps. If I typed in the name of an App I didn't have installed, it would offer to search through the Play Store for me.

This behavior no longer occurs. Instead, now when it can't find an installed App anymore, it automatically changes to a Google Search, but not without emptying my Search query entirely first.

Is there a way to get the old behavior back?

Model and Hardware: FP4

Manufacturer: Fairphone

Build number: FP4.SP1Y.B041.20230109

Comment: If you recently got Android 12 then your phone is not from Google and most likely dos not run plain Android or use it's default launcher app. Please edit your question and add manufacturer and exact model name of your phone. AFAIR the behavior you describe is determined by the launcher app which can be replaced by simply installing a different from Play Store.

Comment: @Robert I added manufacturer, model and build number. I never changed my launcher, I don't know where I can tell which one it uses by default, but I am using the default launcher my phone came with

Comment: Also posted on Fairphone Forum, just in case it gets responses: https://forum.fairphone.com/t/app-search-doesnt-open-in-play-store/93378